# When I overload the assignment operator for my simple class array, I get the wrong answer I expect

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, scope

```
//output is "01234 00000" but the output should be or what I want it to be is 
// "01234 01234" because of the assignment overloaded operator
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class IntArray
{
public:
  IntArray() : size(10), used(0) { a= new int[10]; }
  IntArray(int s) : size(s), used(0) { a= new int[s]; }
  int& operator[]( int index );
  IntArray& operator  =( const IntArray& rightside );
  ~IntArray() { delete [] a; }
private:
  int *a;
  int size;
  int used;//for array position
};

int main()
{
  IntArray copy;
  if( 2>1)
    {
      IntArray arr(5);
      for( int k=0; k<5; k++)
        arr[k]=k;

      copy = arr;
      for( int j=0; j<5; j++)
        cout<<arr[j];
    }
  cout<<" ";
  for( int j=0; j<5; j++)
    cout<<copy[j];

  return 0;
}

int& IntArray::operator[]( int index )
{
  if( index >= size )
    cout<<"ilegal index in IntArray"<<endl;

  return a[index];
}
IntArray& IntArray::operator =( const IntArray& rightside )
{
  if( size != rightside.size )//also checks if on both side same object
    {
      delete [] a;
      a= new int[rightside.size];
    }
  size=rightside.size;
  used=rightside.used;
  for( int i = 0; i < used; i++ )
    a[i]=rightside.a[i];
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: In `operator[]` you should probably also check if `index` is negative.. or make it `unsigned`.

Comment: You should learn to use the copy/swap idiom for the assignment operator. The code you present is the standard first time try and is not exception safe (and does not even provide the basic exception guarantee).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that nowhere in your code sets `used` to anything other than 0 so when you loop from 0 to `used` nothing is copied.

Do you mean to set `used` when you assign to an element in `operator[]` ?

Also, if it's necessary to define a destructor and a copy-assignment operator then you usually (and in this case) need to supply a copy-constructor as well.

Comment: yeah i that was the problem that I had for a hours, thank you.